# Identify this symbol: double emitter transistor?

Tags: schematics

What exactly does this symbol represent, and how is it different from a regular PNP transistor?

[image: one base, two emitters, two collectors]

If it is something more than a basic transistor, how would one model it in a simple [circuit simulator](http://falstad.com/circuit/)?

*From page 8 of [LM78L05 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm78l05.pdf)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a double Collector pnp (the arrow represents the emitter), and can also be interpreted as a current mirror, since it appears to be 2 pnp with shared Emitter and Base.

You can simulate it with 2 transistors, in a mirror configuration.